# Prefect task image can not be pulled from private registry but flow image can

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-registry, prefect

I am trying to run a prefect flow with a single task. My flow has an image for the flow and an image for the task. Both images are in an azure private registry. I am running prefect with kubernetes in an private **non-azure** cluster and the whole prefect stack is deployed via helm while the prefect agent is deployed with a yaml file. My prefect version is 1.4.0

So far:

1. I have created a docker-registry kubernetes secret that holds the credentials for pulling from the registry as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes)
2. I am passing the `IMAGE_PULL_SECRETS` environment variable in the prefect agent with its value being the secret name.
3. I have tried passing the `IMAGE_PULL_SECRETS` to the task via the agent's `PREFECT__CLOUD__AGENT__ENV_VARS` variable with:

   ```
    - name: PREFECT__CLOUD__AGENT__ENV_VARS
      value: '{"IMAGE_PULL_SECRETS: "container-registry-creds"}'
   ```

   which leads to an error even before creating the job pod

What I observe is that when running a flow, the flow image is pulled from the registry but when it is time to run the task, the task image can not be pulled and I get the following error from the pod description:

```
Failed to pull image "<registry>/<image>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head https://<registry-name>.azurecr.io/v2/<image>/manifests/<image-tag>: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
```

I think this issue is not an azure issue because I successfully pulled a pod from the private registry using the same docker-registry secret.

Answer (score 0):

What's your prefect version?

It looks like you are running this with Prefect 1 on Azure AKS, correct?

Can you explain what is meant by task image vs job image?

Generally, you could attach secrets directly to the agent start command in v1:

```py
prefect agent kubernetes start --image-pull-secrets secret-1,secret-2
```

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question. I am using prefect 1.4.0. I am using it in a cluster that is not in azure. The container registry however is in azure.  By job image I meant the flow image while task image is the image that runs the task. I have already tried passing the secret to the agent but still no luck.